# Como pegar o ID de auto incremento usando MySQL e PHP e usar depois?

Tags: php, mysql, api, sql-insert

Estou criando uma API em PHP e inserção. Preciso pegar o ID criado neste INSERT e usar depois. O que encontro de material, parece não ser recomendado. Alguma solução? Obrigado.

Meu PHP:

```
    <?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    //formulário

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $objData = json_decode($data);

    // TRANSFORMA OS DADOS

    $nome = $_GET['nome'];
    $endereco = $_GET['endereco'];
    $numero = $_GET['numero'];
 //   $complemento = $_GET['complemento'];
    $bairro = $_GET['bairro'];
    $cidade = $_GET['cidade'];
    $estado = $_GET['estado'];
    $cod_cliente = $_GET['cod_cliente'];
    $outro_endereco_cod = $_GET['outro_endereco_cod'];
    $forma_pagamento = $_GET['forma_pagamento'];
    $troco = $_GET['troco'];
    $frete = $_GET['frete'];
    $valor_pedido = $_GET['valor_pedido'];
    $cod_fornecedor = $_GET['cod_fornecedor'];
    $total_pedido = $_GET['total_pedido'];

     // INSERE OS DADOS
    $db = new PDO("DADOS DA MINHA CONEXAO");


    if($db){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO dados_pedido (nome, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cod_cliente, outro_endereco_cod, forma_pagamento, troco, frete, valor_pedido, cod_fornecedor, total_pedido) VALUES ('$nome', '$endereco', '$numero', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$estado', '$cod_cliente', '$outro_endereco_cod', '$forma_pagamento', '$troco', '$frete', '$valor_pedido', '$cod_fornecedor', '$total_pedido')";


        $query = $db->prepare($sql); 

        $query ->execute();    





        echo json_encode(array('message'=> ' Os dados foram inseridos com sucesso. Obrigado e bem vindo!' ));
    }else{
        echo json_decode(array('message'=> ' Não foi possivel iserir os dados! Tente novamente mais tarde!' ));
    };

?>
```

Comment: Já tentou `$id = $db->lastInsertId();`?

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Colocarei como resposta para poder sinalizar como respondido

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe PDO, no PHP 5.1.0+, possui um método chamado [`lastInsertID`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php), conforme documentação oficial.

> **PDO::lastInsertId** — *Returns the ID of the last inserted row or sequence value*

Assim, após executar sua *query*, basta retomar o valor de `$db->lastInsertId()` para obter o *id* do novo registro.

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();

echo "Último id inserido: " . $id;
```

O trecho de código acima seria um exemplo simples de como utilizar o último *id* inserido.

> **Nota**: *This method may not return a meaningful or consistent result across different PDO drivers, because the underlying database may not even support the notion of auto-increment fields or sequences.*

Comment: Uma dica, antes de responder confira na busca se já não existe resposta para a duvida e então marque a pergunta como duplicata, exemplo de busca http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=lastInsertId (discussão no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5719/3635)